# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-contentprovider, genymotion

why the acquireProvider method return null ?
I defined a provider like this:

```
public class PersonProvider extends ContentProvider {

private SQLiteHelper helper;

private static final UriMatcher MATCHER = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static {
    //初始化要匹配的uri,当匹配成功就会返回code
    MATCHER.addURI("com.example.provider.PersonProvider", "person", 1);
    //MATCHER.addURI("com.example.provider.PersonProvider", "person", 2);
    //MATCHER.addURI("com.example.provider.PersonProvider", "person", 3);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    String createTableSql = "CREATE TABLE person(id integer primary key autoincrement, name varchar(20))";
    helper = new SQLiteHelper(this.getContext(), "person.db", createTableSql);
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

    switch (MATCHER.match(uri)) {
        case ProviderConstant.i_person:
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            //当value为空时，相当于insert into person(name) value(NULL)
            long id = db.insert("person", "name", values);
            ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("参数有错");
    }
    return uri;
    }
}
```

and then, I defined it in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="OtherActivity" />

    <provider android:authorities="com.example.provider.PersonProvider" android:name="com.example.provider.PersonProvider"/>
</application>
```

and then, I invoke it in other app:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class PersonProviderTest {
@Test
public void testInsert() {

    //uri = schema + authorities + path
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(ProviderConstant.CONTENT_PRE + ProviderConstant.AUTHORITIES + "/person");
    ContentResolver resolver = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", "xiaom");
    values.put("phone", 12);
    resolver.insert(uri, values);
    }
}
```

the constant:

```
public static final String CONTENT_PRE = "content://";
public static final String AUTHORITIES = "com.example.provider.PersonProvider";
```

when I run the class, I got some error msg:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.example.provider.PersonProvider/person
```

and then, I tried to debug the code and found that:the acquireProvider method return null:

```
public final IContentProvider acquireProvider(Uri uri) {
    if (!SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
        return null;
    }
    final String auth = uri.getAuthority();
    if (auth != null) {
        return acquireProvider(mContext, auth);   //here return null!!
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If I gather this correctly your actual question boils down to why a certain method call returns `null`. In order to get this answered you should figure you what the _actual_ parameter values are for the erroneous call and provide the values of `mContext` and `auth`. Maybe then a knowledgeable soul will be able to help you.

Comment: I can't find out why I got the error.

Comment: Let me try to be more clear. You most probably tracks down your problem to `acquireProvider(mContext, auth)` returning `null`. In this form nobody (in his right mind) will be able to answer your question. As you already have debugged the code you should be able to set a breakpoint and determine the values of `mContext` and `auth`. If you post these values here, maybe somebody will be able to spot the error (but more probably you will then find it yourself :-).

Comment: yes,I had solve this problem.because I deployed the provider code and contentSolver code to different virtual device.finally thanks for your answer.